# Множественное сравнение

Tags: c#

Есть условная переменная id и проверка на соответствие разным значениям.

```
if (id == 1 || id == 2 || id == 3)
```

Вообще сравнений около 10ти. Есть ли вариант укоротить код? Например как в Python или около того.

Comment: а как в python? И что помешало попробовать применить тот самый способ "как в питон"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сформировать коллекцию элементов из требуемых значений и использовать функцую `Constains()` как показал в ответе @User:

```
var array = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };

if (array.Contains(id)) // using System.Linq
{

}
```

Если значений не так много (например 2-5), то можно обойтись элегантно и без создания коллекции:

```
if (id is 1 or 2 or 3)
{

}
```

Если значения идут по-порядку, то ещё проще:

```
if (id is >= 1 and <= 3)
{

}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
using System.Linq;
Int32[] array = new Int32[]{1,2,3,4,5};
if(array.Contains(id))
{

}
```